# LTSpice parametric subcircuit instances

Tags: spice, ltspice

I want to compare signals from my `fancy` subcircuit (very complex) and multiple subcircuits `level1` (should be almost equivalent, but simpler) with different parameters; these parameters should be passed to `level2` subcircuits.

Below is a (simplified) nonworking sample code:

```
Xfncy 2 0 fancy
Xlvl10 2 0 level1 PARAMS: Y1=1 Y2=1
Xlvl11 2 0 level1 PARAMS: Y1=1 Y2=10
Xlvl12 2 0 level1 PARAMS: Y1=10 Y2=1
Xlvl13 2 0 level1 PARAMS: Y1=10 Y2=10

.SUBCKT fancy 1 2 
* STUFF
.ENDS fancy

.SUBCKT level1 1 2 PARAMS: Y1=1 Y2=2

.param Z10=1 Z20=1 Z11=1 Z21=1 Z12=1 Z22=1

Xlvl20 1 2 level2 PARAMS: Y3=Z10*Y1 Y3=Z20*Y2
Xlvl21 1 2 level2 PARAMS: Y3=Z11*Y1 Y4=Z21*Y2
...
...
Xlvl28 1 2 level2 PARAMS: Y3=Z18*Y1 Y4=Z28*Y2


.SUBCKT level2 1 2 PARAMS: Y3=1 Y4=1
* STUFF
.ENDS level2
.ENDS level1
```

Running like this, I get the following error:

> WARNING: Can't resolve .param Y3=Z10*Y1
>
> Select OK to continue the simulation with the default model or Cancel to quit now

My first version of the  instance `Xlvl20` line:

```
Xlvl20 1 2 level2 PARAMS: Y3={Z10*Y1} Y3={Z20*Y2}
```

yields the same error. If I change the line to:

```
Xlvl20 1 2 level2 PARAMS: {Y3=Z10*Y1 Y3=Z20*Y2}
```

I get:

> Missing expression in
>
> "{Y3=Z10*Y1 Y3=Z20*Y2}"

Is passing parameters like this even possible in LTSpice and if so, how? Alternative approaches are also welcome.

PS: Yes, I've tried `.step param` to avoid packing `level1` stuff into a subcircuit, but then I can't compare it to `fancy`, because `fancy` takes about 30 times more time to simulate.

Comment: It looks like you're defining Y3 twice. That could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The LTSpice [manual](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mathys/ecen1400/pdf/scad3.pdf) gives an example of how to do this:

```
* calling a subcircuit
*
* This is the circuit
X1 in out 0 divider top=9K bot=1K
V1 in 0 pulse(0 1 0 .5m .5m 0 1m)

* This is the subcircuit
.subckt divider A B C
R1 A B {top}
R2 B C {bot}
.ends divider
.tran 3m
.end
```

The full syntax is given as:

```
Syntax: Xxxx n1 n2 n3... <subckt name> [<parameter>=<expression>]
```

The rules for writing expressions are given in the section of the manual on "arbitrary behavioral voltage and current sources".